# Swift Unary operator '!' cannot be applied to an operand of type 'OLVideoCell'

Tags: swift

```
  //This is in the UITableViewCell class method
  class func videoCellWithTableView(tableview:UITableView) -> OLVideoCell{

  var cell = tableview .dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("OLVideoCell") as! OLVideoCell

  // “!cell” Why you will be prompted “ Unary operator '!' cannot be applied to an operand of type 'OLVideoCell'”

  if !cell {

        cell = OLVideoCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "OLVideoCell")

        cell.selectionStyle = .None

    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Because this is Swift and `cell` is not a `Bool`. Write your condition like so: `cell == nil`.

Comment: Thank But  will be prompt “Value of type 'OLVideoCell' can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed”

Comment: Because you force cast your cell to a non-optional type. If you expect `nil` there, use optional type.

Answer (score 1):

if cell == nil,The value of any condition in an if statement must have a type that conforms to the BooleanType protocol. The condition can also be an optional binding declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your code like so:

```
import UIKit

class OLVideoCell: UITableViewCell {

    class func videoCellWithTableView(tableview: UITableView) -> OLVideoCell {
        // Use `as?` to allow `nil` as a result.
        var cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("OLVideoCell") as? OLVideoCell
        // The condition has to be of boolean type.
        if  cell == nil {
            cell = OLVideoCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "OLVideoCell")
            cell!.selectionStyle = .None
        }
        return cell! // And the result has to be non-optional.
    }

}
```